# Insanely huge numbers in symbolic variables after assigning double

Tags: matlab

I first define some differential equations:

```
%% Definitions
% Constants
syms L R J Ke p
% Input
syms ud uq m
% Output
syms id iq ome theta
% Derivations
syms did diq dome dtheta
%% Equations
did=(ud/L)-(R/L)*id+ome*iq;
diq=(uq/L)-(R/L)*iq-ome*id-(Ke/L)*ome;
dome = (p/J)*((3/2)*p*Ke*iq-m);
dtheta = ome;
```

I'm trying to calculate `R` and `L` now. The input and output variables come from simulink:

```
idvalues = DQ_OUT.signals.values(:,1);
iqvalues = DQ_OUT.signals.values(:,2);
udvalues = UIdq.signals.values(:,1);
uqvalues = UIdq.signals.values(:,2);
% ... define some position in these arrays ...
% Define values for symbolic variables
id=idvalues(position);
ud=udvalues(position);
iq=iqvalues(position);
ome=iqvalues(position);
```

These are double. I then `eval` the first equation:

```
eval(did)
```

And I get this crap:

```
ans =

6002386699416615/(18014398509481984*L) - (846927175344863*R)/(1125899906842624*L) + 4168268387464377/9007199254740992
```

I was thinking that mathematics calculator like matlab won't bother you with variable types, but what I see here is definitely variable type problem - the actual values are less than 1:

[image: image description]

Specifically:

```
id = 0.7522
ud = 0.3332
iq = 0.6803
ome = 0.6803
```

Comment: Try `vpa(eval(did))`

Comment: Thanks! Not only that it now shows correct numbers, but also is simplified: `0.333/L - (0.752*R)/L + 0.462` (I deleted excess digits). Could you post an answer and explain why my code did not work and how your fix works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing symbolic calculations, Matlab uses rational numbers for small decimals. This prevents floating point numerical issues and keeps the results exact. However as you found, it makes the results harder to read.

Matlab also has a `vpa` (variable precision arithmetic) function, which is capable of keeping up to 2^(29)+1 digits (apparently) in calculations, which means Matlab doesn't need to stick to rational functions in order to maintain exact results.

Before viewing the output of a symbolic calculation, use `vpa` to convert rational numbers with large numerators/denominators to decimal expansions, by using, in your case, `vpa(eval(did))`.

For example, defining

```
syms a
b=0.75221
```

then `a*b` gives

```
>> a*b
ans =
(75221*a)/100000
```

but `vpa(a*b)` gives

```
>> vpa(a*b)
ans =
0.75221*a
```

Comment: Also, depending on what else is in your code, you could probably define `did`, `diq`, etc. after `id`, `ud`, etc. and you may may not need to use `eval`.

Comment: What do you mean by defining diq?

Comment: Where you did `did=(ud/L)-(R/L)*id+ome*iq;`, and `diq=(uq/L)-(R/L)*iq-ome*id-(Ke/L)*ome;`, if you do those after you have found the values of `iq`, `id` etc. then you shouldn't need to use `eval`.